# Unable to customize sign-in page of my tenant

Tags: azure-authentication, azure-rbac

I have created users in my Azure AD tenant using  bulk create template in Azure Portal.

I want to customize the sign-in page when my users are logging in to Azure Portal.

I found that we can use company branding to achieve that.
But, I cannot find that option in my tenant.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieq0x.png)

Is there any other setting that are required to enable that option?
Am I missing anything?
Do I need any permissions or RBAC roles specifically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

•   To be able to customize your sign-in page through the **‘Company Branding’** feature in Azure Active Directory, `you will need the permissions and privileges of a ‘Global Administrator’`. That is, **you will have to sign in with the assigned role of a ‘Global Administrator’ for that tenant or Azure AD Directory**.

Thus, **you will have to be a ‘Global Administrator’ to be able to customize your sign-in page through the Azure Portal and to be able to do so, i.e., to enable that option in your tenant**.

•   Please find the documentation link below that describes the configuration of company branding features for an Azure AD tenant: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/customize-branding#customize-your-azure-ad-sign-in-page

Also, to `read the configuration regarding the ‘Company Branding’, you will need atleast ‘Directory Reader’ role while that user also should be a default user`. Please find the below documentation for the above said least privileged required roles: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/delegate-by-task#company-branding

Update : - Because, in my tenant, I have the assigned role of a Global administrator and I am able to configure the required through Company branding feature. Please check in the below snapshots: -

[image: Global Administrator role]
[image: Company Branding feature]
[image: Configuring Company branding]

Comment: I already have the roles you mentioned but still I can't find that option

Comment: If you are a global administrator and have logged in with that user ID, then you should be able to see that option and configure the Company branding feature. Kindly check the updated answer and the links provided in it. Also, if the answer is satisfactory, you can accept it.

Comment: It turned out that, after purchasing Azure AD Premium P2 license I'm able to see that option

Comment: Yes, Azure AD license is necessary for customizing the Azure AD tenant. Similarly, purchasing license is necessary for every Microsoft product to unlock customization features.